# Linear combination of gaussian variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, gaussian-integral

If $X\sim N(0,\sigma_1^2)$,$Y\sim N(0,\sigma_2^2)$ and given that X,Y are independent random variable with normal distributions, then for the random variable $U=\alpha X+\beta Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ ($\alpha,\beta$ are constants), What is the mean and variance of this new Gasusian distribtuion $U$ in closed form? Does this generalise indefinitely? Is $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=\alpha^2\sigma_1^2+\beta\sigma_2^2$?

Comment: That's almost right$-$you forgot to square $\beta$, which I assume was a typo. Also, it does generalize indefinitely. See if [this page](http://www.statlect.com/normal_distribution_linear_combinations.htm) helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, close.  Indeed $\mu = 0$, but $\sigma = \sqrt{\alpha^2 \sigma_1^2 +  \beta^2 \sigma_2^2} $.

I suspect you just mis-typed leaving out the power of 2 in both sigma and beta.

And yes it does generalize.

Comment: What if we had $U=\alpha X-\beta Y\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$? Would it change the results?